# Combine two Path figures in one?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, path, geometry

I'm having these two shapes:

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]

Fist picture code:

```
<Path Fill="Orange">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,100">
                <BezierSegment Point1="50,110" Point2="50,110" Point3="100,100"></BezierSegment>
                <LineSegment Point="100,80"></LineSegment>
                <LineSegment Point="120,90"></LineSegment>
                <LineSegment Point="120,70"></LineSegment>
                <LineSegment Point="100,60"></LineSegment>
                <LineSegment Point="100,20"></LineSegment>
                <LineSegment Point="80,0"></LineSegment>
                <LineSegment Point="20,0"></LineSegment>
                <LineSegment Point="0,20"></LineSegment>
                <LineSegment Point="0,40"></LineSegment>
                <LineSegment Point="-20,20"></LineSegment>
                <LineSegment Point="-20,40"></LineSegment>
                <LineSegment Point="0,60"></LineSegment>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Second picture code:

```
<Path Fill="Orange">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure>
                <LineSegment Point="0,25"></LineSegment>
                <LineSegment Point="250,25"></LineSegment>
                <LineSegment Point="250,0"></LineSegment>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

How do i combine them for something like this(ignore the text):
[image]

I need this to be done in C# ( not xaml ). Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

> For users wanting to know the XAML method

Basically, you can use a `CombinedGeometry` object to do this:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#CCCCFF">
    <Path.Data>
        <!-- Combines two geometries using the exclude combine mode. -->
        <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Union">
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="0,100">
                        <BezierSegment Point1="50,110" Point2="50,110" Point3="100,100"></BezierSegment>
                        <LineSegment Point="100,80"></LineSegment>
                        <LineSegment Point="120,90"></LineSegment>
                        <LineSegment Point="120,70"></LineSegment>
                        <LineSegment Point="100,60"></LineSegment>
                        <LineSegment Point="100,20"></LineSegment>
                        <LineSegment Point="80,0"></LineSegment>
                        <LineSegment Point="20,0"></LineSegment>
                        <LineSegment Point="0,20"></LineSegment>
                        <LineSegment Point="0,40"></LineSegment>
                        <LineSegment Point="-20,20"></LineSegment>
                        <LineSegment Point="-20,40"></LineSegment>
                        <LineSegment Point="0,60"></LineSegment>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="0,100">
                        <LineSegment Point="0,25"></LineSegment>
                        <LineSegment Point="250,25"></LineSegment>
                        <LineSegment Point="250,0"></LineSegment>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
        </CombinedGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Please take a look at the [How to: Create a Combined Geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746682.aspx) page on MSDN for full details.

Please also note that you will need to set the `StartPoint` property of these `PathFigure` objects to correctly line up your shapes.

UPDATE >>>

> For users wanting to know the C# method

Sorry, I didn't notice that you wanted to use code. In code you would have to name your `PathGeometry` objects and put them into a `Resources` section:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <PathGeometry x:Key="Shape1">
        ...
    </PathGeometry>
    <PathGeometry x:Key="Shape2">
        ...
    </PathGeometry>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then you can still use a `CombinedGeometry` object:

```
PathGeometry shape1 = (PathGeometry)Application.Current.FindResource("Shape1");
PathGeometry shape2 = (PathGeometry)Application.Current.FindResource("Shape2");
CombinedGeometry combinedGeometry = new CombinedGeometry(
    GeometryCombineMode.Union, shape1, shape2);
Path combinedPath = new Path();
combinedPath.Data = combinedGeometry;
```

Please take a look at the [CombinedGeometry Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.combinedgeometry.aspx) page at MSDN for more information with this method.

Comment: Accepted... I didn't see that... thanks.

Comment: I have to say i want and i like the xaml method